# Parse Issue Unexpected '@' in Program

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios) from Dropbox and when I build and run my app I'm getting `Parse Issue Unexpected '@' in Program` (see attached screenshots). What's wrong?

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't actually in whatever file you are including this .h file into?

Comment: I think you could be including an Objective-C header in a C or C++ file.

Comment: What is the filename of the file that includes or imports this one? If it ends in anything other than ".m" or ".mm", then the compiler will assumes it's not Objective-C and give you errors like these.

Comment: Maybe because the .h file doesn't include or import anything?

Comment: Can you stick this project up on Github and send over the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import UIKit .Will solve the problem

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```